# Ansible Jinja template if statement

Tags: ansible, jinja, templating

This is a snippet from my Ansible jinja template which populates an environment specific template.

```
docker_compose_mq: <string-passed from Jenkins>
docker_compose_profiles: "string"

{% if "{{ risk_docker_compose_mq }}" == "string" %}
  {% "{{ risk_docker_compose_profiles: "string1" }}" %}
{% endif %}
```

This fails with a pretty generic error message:

```
"Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'True': line 26, column 2, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\n(could not open file to display line)"}
```

I'm almost certain it's to do with escaping the quotes here but can't for the life of me work out what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Could you try this https://gist.github.com/halberom/794c06598f40ccc31560?

Comment: No luck with this either - Convinced it must be something wrong with another aspect of my Ansible setup... @030

Answer (score 3):

The syntax failures are caused by the presence of the `{{...}}` [expression](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#expressions) blocks (normally used for filling the template output with the corresponding content) inside the `{%...%}` [statement](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#list-of-control-structures) blocks.

I only used standalone jinja2 templates, so I'm not 100% certain if this applies to Ansible jinja templates as well, but I suspect so. In the Jinja2 `{%...%}` statement blocks variables are referenced directly (and variable assignments are done in `{% set ...%}` statements), so what you're after may be along these lines:

```
{% set docker_compose_mq = <string-passed from Jenkins> %}
{% set docker_compose_profiles = "string" %}

{% if risk_docker_compose_mq == "string" %}
  {% set risk_docker_compose_profiles = "string1" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Didn't work out unfortunately. Maybe something deeper in my Ansible estate causing these issues.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is the below one:

```
{% if backup_dest[0:1]  == "/" %}
```

=> this one tests if "backup_dest" first character is "/"

```
{% if variable == "blabla" %}
```

=> this one tests if "variable" equals to "blabla"

Regards